# XPath - find first occurance of string

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to select an anchor element by first containing the text "To Be Coded", then extracting a number from a string using substring, then using the greater than comparison operator (>0).  This is what I have thus far:

```
/a[number(substring(text(),???,string-length()-1))>0]
```

An example of the HTML is:

```
<a class="" href="javascript:submitRequest('getRec','30', '63', 'Z')">
                                    To Be Coded&nbsp;&nbsp;(23)
</a>
```

My issue right now is I don't know how to find the first occurrence of the open parenthesis.  I'm also not sure how to combine what I have with the contains(text(),"To Be Coded") function.

So my criteria for the selection is:

- Must be an anchor element
- Must include the text "To Be Coded"
- Must contain a number greater than 0 in the parentheses

Edit: I suppose I could just "hard code" the starting position for the substring, but I'm not sure what that would be - will XPath count the white space before the text in the element?  How would it handle/count the `&nbsp;` characters?

Comment: I think it's 1.0 - the XPath is for selenium/firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here try this :

```
a[contains(.,  'To Be Coded') and number(substring-before(substring-after(., '('), ')')) > 0]
```

Comment: No problem. Note that this will fail if the content of the anchor has more than one parentheses.